# Sanity CMS: Get current user from datastore

Tags: sanity, user-identification

I'm trying to fetch the current user in Sanity CMS.

I found this code snippet which demonstrates use of [userStore](https://www.sanity.io/schemas/usecurrentuser-custom-react-hook-976529a6)

But I don't understand how I can configure my project to accept this module lookup

```js
import userStore from 'part:@sanity/base/user';
```

It throws an import error `Cannot find module 'part:@sanity/base/user'`. Which makes sense as its a non standard node module.

1. How can I resolve this so the module is found?
2. Or alternatively anyone know another way to fetch the current user?

Inspecting that `@sanity` source I can see `base/lib/datastores` which has a `userStore` it's just not obvious how to consume this.

Answer (score 0):

So this example hook works and returns the User. Sanity is taking care of the module resolution. It's an IDE error not a runtime error in Sanity.

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Their advice is to [ignore](https://www.sanity.io/docs/parts#e778915da57f) these un resolved module warnings for part imports.

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
      "import/no-unresolved": [2, { "ignore": ["^(all|part):"] }]
    }
  },
```